# Can part of a website be static site generated and the other be a traditional spa?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, ssg, static-site-generation

So, I've built a website in Nuxt and used ssg. It's great, but for another website 90% of it is all static text and images, but I want a customer login portal where they can see statuses of their products. With my understanding, I don't see how this could be ssg as well. So is it possible to have both?

Comment: You meant: "and used SSR" ? Or do you mean: "generated on the server" by _ssg_ ?

Comment: @kissu, Sorry, I mean "generated on the server by ssg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`generate-exclude`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#exclude) configuration can help you avoiding to SSR specific pages.

So, let's say we have this

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    exclude: [
      /^\/admin/ // path starts with /admin
    ]
  }
}
```

It will SSR render everything but the `admin` path, this one will only be available as an SPA generated route.

---

EDIT to answer to the comments

If you have this kind of structure, all the nested routes under `admin` will be rendered as SPA pages. `blog` and `pricing` would still be universal (`server` + `client` rendered).

Also, a simple `admin.vue` can also do the job yeah (if no more routes needed).

```
pages
--admin
----secure-dashboard.vue
----info.vue
--blog
--pricing
```

For the cache, I'm not sure exactly how it behaves but it should still be working, since it's browser side. Not really depending of the type of rendering.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. So I could have an `admin.vue` file in the pages directory of the Nuxt app, but it would be treated an a traditional SPA vs how it would treat an SSG route with it's cached assets and api calls?

Answer (score 2):

Vue.js is rendered into #app. Everything outside of that div will be static. So yes, you can have both. BTW, if you don't need SPA completely, check for  alphine.js which is a lightweight alternative.

Comment: You can't really write any code outside of the basic scope (`#app` div). In a clean way at least. Also, I'm not sure that bringing alpine is a thing to do when you already have a JS framework. It usually used in pure HTML+CSS context only.

Comment: You can't write any Vue code outside of #app, but you can write Vanilla JS. So you can have both, and they can be very clear. Alphine is not for using among Vue, it's an alternative. If you build a page with 90% of static content, it's not logical to use any big framework.