# Nuxt3 - SSG for specific pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to know can we use server-side rendering for specific page in nuxt.

**This is what I want to achieve**

**Rendered on Server**

```
www.example.com/foo
```

**Rendered on Client**

```
www.example.com/bar
```

Comment: Please clarify, SSR or SSG? Also, do you want some of them to be SPA-only + SSR/SSG or do you want to have some with SSR and other with SSG example? [This one](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/560) may be a good starting point. Your updated example doesn't make a lot of sense, since you're sharing a path change.

Comment: Accidently delete this Question xD. Actually, I want to edit this question, but I Accidently click + enter on delete.
Anyways I actually want my whole site rendered in the browser except for few pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472634/8816585) regarding the same use-case.
In Nuxt3, it is still available under this [exclude key](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt-config#exclude).

You can achieve some pages in SSG (`/` in our case) and some other in SPA (`/about` in our case)

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    index default page, seen even without JS
  </div>
</template>
```

`/pages/about.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    about page only available when JS is enabled
  </div>
</template>
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  generate: {
    exclude: [
      /^\/about/
    ]
  }
})
```

You can disable your JS thanks to browser's devtools or inspect the source code to see that the `/about` page doesn't have any statically generated content (and only works with JS enabled).

---

At some point, the syntax will be as [shown here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/560) aka

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routes: {
    '/': { prerender: true }, // Once per build (via builder)
    '/blog/*': { static: true }, // Once on-demand per build (via lambda)
    '/stats/*': { swr: '10 min' }, // Once on-demand each 10 minutes (via lambda)
    '/admin/*': { ssr: false }, // Client-Side rendered
    '/react/*': { redirect: '/vue' }, // Redirect Rules
  }
})
```

But this is still in the works and not fully done yet as far as I know. In the meantime, I'm proposing the "old way" of doing such things.