# How turn on ssr for one page?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

how i can turn on ssr mode for only one page? Without enabled ssr option globally and use serverMiddleware for set spa mode for all pages instead specific page?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot enable `SSR` for only one page. Meanwhile, you could enable it globally and set everything but one to be using SPA-only.

As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472634/8816585

PS: assuming you're using Nuxt2.